# File recovery data copy

Tags: command-line, mount, raid

This is my first time using Ubuntu, and I'm using it to recover data from the drives of my dead READYNAS.

The commands used to access/mount the RAID were obtained from here:
http://www.readynas.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=74912

(1) sudo su

(2) apt-get install fuseext2

(3) apt-get install lvm2

(4) modprobe fuse

(5) vgscan

(6) vgchange -ay c

(7) fuseext2 -o ro -o sync_read /dev/c/c /mnt

I've been able to cp off much of the data, but have run into an access issue, I think.

Here's my terminal window:

root@nusheen-P5Q-E:/mnt/media# dir -a

.  ..  Audio\ Books  BitTorrent  .DS_Store  Ebooks  Homer64.log  Music  Music2  Pictures  Scan\ share  Software  Transfer  Videos

root@nusheen-P5Q-E:/mnt/media# cd software

bash: cd: software: No such file or directory

root@nusheen-P5Q-E:/mnt/media#

The same error presents for the Music and Music2 folders, but they copied off okay using commands like this:

cp -r -u -v Music /media/nusheen/3TB/Music

when I try to copy off the Software folder to another drive connected via the same case I used for the 3TB drive, I get this:

root@nusheen-P5Q-E:/mnt/media# cp -r -u -v software /media/nusheen/RAID/software

cp: cannot stat ‘software’: No such file or directory

root@nusheen-P5Q-E:/mnt/media#

Any suggestions?

Cheers,
Nusheen

Comment: you should really be using sudo for each command

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll be sure to for the rest of the copy process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike windows, Linux is case sensitive. Use this:

```
cd Software
```

instead of:

```
cd software
```

because "software" does not exist but "Software" does.

Comment: Thank you! So silly of me not to try that earlier.

Comment: @Nusheen if this is the answer please close it out by accepting the answer by clicking the icon on the left. Thanks!